# Calendar event is not shown in the calendar

Tags: android, xamarin, calendar

I have an android App created in xamarin forms where I add a calendar event using the below code.

```
enterContentValues eventValues = new ContentValues();
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, eventId);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, Title);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, Description);
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "Local");
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtstart, GetDateTimeMS(StartDate.Year, StartDate.Month, StartDate.Day, StartDate.Hour, StartDate.Minute));
            eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Dtend, GetDateTimeMS(EndDate.Year, EndDate.Month, EndDate.Day, EndDate.Hour, EndDate.Minute));
            var uri = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues);
            Console.WriteLine("Uri for new event: {0}", uri);
            long eventID = long.Parse(uri.LastPathSegment);
            return true;
```

I am not getting any exceptions in executing the function. Also I am getting the uri and eventID. However after execution of this, I am not able to see the event added in the calendar. Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer...

This line of code,
eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, eventId);

I was passing different eventId for each event add to calendar .. ie i am creating an id for an event and that id is passed. Now instead of passing this different, I passed only 1 as parameter.

ie eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);

It worked!!!

Comment: Congratulations! I was using code like `eventValues.Put(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.CalendarId, 1);`, but it doesn't shown by my side, I think it's because my calendar app of system is customized. Anyway, congratulations for self-solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The calendar content provider is not part of the Android SDK. It may not work on some devices where they have replaced the default calendar application with their own. Please check this blog: [Be Careful With Content Providers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html).

If you double checked your app's permission and your code, and still can't find any problem, then if you don't mind, you can use `Intent` to insert calendar event for example like this:

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
calIntent.SetData(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri);
calIntent.SetType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "Test Event from M4A");
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "This is an event created from Xamarin.Android");

long lDtStart = GetDateTimeMS(2017, 9, 20, 14, 0);
long lDtEnd = GetDateTimeMS(2017, 9, 20, 16, 0);

calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventBeginTime, lDtStart);
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventEndTime, lDtEnd);

calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "UTC");
calIntent.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "UTC");

StartActivity(calIntent);
```

**Update**

To request these permissions at runtime, you can for example code like this:

```
private readonly string[] PermissionsCalendar =
{
    Manifest.Permission.ReadCalendar,
    Manifest.Permission.WriteCalendar
};

private const int RequestCalendarId = 0;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout);

    ...

    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
    {
        var permissionread = Manifest.Permission.ReadCalendar;
        var permissionwrite = Manifest.Permission.WriteCalendar;
        if (CheckSelfPermission(permissionread) != (int)Permission.Granted || CheckSelfPermission(permissionwrite) != (int)P
        {
            RequestPermissions(PermissionsCalendar, RequestCalendarId);
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO：
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO:
    }
    ...
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case RequestCalendarId:
            {
                if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                {
                    //Permission granted
                    //TODO：
                }
                else
                {
                    //Permission Denied :(
                    //TODO：
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Feng - Hi Grace, thanks for your answer. I tried using intent, but the problem here is the calendar will popup and ask for saving/cancelling the event addition to calendar. Here I will not get to know inside my code whether the user has cancelled or user has saved.  Also i could see that most of the mobile has only its calendar and not a separate calendar app. Then i have provided the permission for android and this is what...

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
</manifest>

Comment: @hashimks, for android version above 23, it is needed to require the permission at runtime.

Comment: How can i set it?

Comment: @hashimks, I updated my answer for requesting permissions.

Comment: its not complete.. i am getting some errors at
1.  'P'

Comment: @hashimks, I replaced some code with "...", try to remove this punctuation, works by my side, if you want to understand how it works, maybe you can check [this doc](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/).

Comment: Yes .. I got it.. thanks.. :) .. I will try with this once

Comment: Hi.. I tried this, but still its not adding to calendar. I have some doubt on the eventId.. this can cause any issues? I am passing a string eventID, which I am creating

Comment: @hashimks, did you get some exception for example like "column '_id' is invalid"?

Comment: No exceptions at all.. i am getting value in var uri = Forms.Context.ContentResolver.Insert(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri, eventValues); .. but not seeing in the calendar

Comment: Feng .. Hi, anything u found out?

Comment: @hashimks, no, I'm getting the same result as you, but my phone uses customized android system, the calendar is changed. This is why I suggest to use intent, but you want to insert event silently.

Comment: Feng ... Yes i want it to insert silently... so this is an issue now for all people?

Comment: Feng --- I found the answer... Please see it